# How to draw multiple non-time series in Grafana Trend x!= time visualization

Tags: grafana

I am trying to draw seven series returned from a group by query in influx DB where the axis values come integer type tag.
Unfortunately, the trend can display only 1 series(if I filter out the other six series).
Grafan shows "Only one frame is supported, consider adding a join transformation". Is there a way around to void this error? I know time series visualization can do this but in that case, I cannot display desired x values on the x-axis. I also tried to achieve this with XY charts but in that case, tooltips are not working and I cannot select a subset of the series with mouse click.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed join data from multiple queries or use another plugins. For instance, plotly.